# React Native error - Unable to resolve module `./tab-bar-item-ios`

Tags: react-native, react-native-vector-icons

Ive just upgraded `react-native-vector-icons` from version 7.1 to 8.0......and now Im getting the following error:

```
    unable to resolve module `./tab-bar-item-ios` from `node_modules\react-native-vector-icons\lib\create-icon-set.js`
    None of these files exist:
  * node_modules\react-native-vector-icons\lib\tab-bar-item-ios(.native|.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.json|.native.json|.json|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx).........etc
```

Im testing on real Android device, using a windows computer.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It's a cache problem, you can fix it running:

```
react-native start --reset-cache
```

Created this account just to answer your question hehe, i know how frustrating those errors can be.

Comment: Very interesting indeed......I hear this solution very often, proposed for many different code ailments....and it has NEVER worked as a solution for me......until now!!.  First time ever :).  Cheers!

Comment: Working for me. If not try ' npm start -- --reset-cache '

Comment: I think it should be given in documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Did you use caret(^) when specifying version of react-native-vector-icons?
I had same error message and it worked for me after removing '^'

"react-native-vector-icons": "^8.0.0" => "react-native-vector-icons": "8.0.0"

Comment: No removing caret didnt work for me.  Caret or not...as of today....8.0.0 is installed and this causes the issue